# Embedding Python to C++ Segmentation fault

Tags: python, c++, c, multithreading

I am trying to track the execution of python scripts with C++ Threads (If anyone knows a better approach, feel free to mention it)

This is the code I have so far.

```
#define PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN
#include </usr/include/python3.8/Python.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

void launchScript(const char *filename){
    Py_Initialize();
    FILE *fd = fopen(filename, "r");
    PyRun_SimpleFile(fd, filename);
    PyErr_Print();
    Py_Finalize();
 

}
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    Py_Initialize();
    PyRun_SimpleString("import sys");
    PyRun_SimpleString("sys.path.append(\".\")");
    std::thread first (launchScript,"script.py");
    std::cout << "Thread 1 is running with thread ID: " << first.get_id() << std::endl;
    std::thread second (launchScript,"script2.py");
    std::cout << "Thread 2 is running with thread ID: " << second.get_id() << std::endl;
   
    first.join();
    second.join();
    Py_Finalize();
    return 0; 
   
}
```

Script.py just has a print statement that prints "Hello World"
Script2.py has a print statement that prints "Goodbye World"

I build the application with the following commands

```
g++ -pthread -I/usr/include/python3.8/ main.cpp -L/usr/lib/python3.8/config-3.8-x86_64 linux-gnu -lpython3.8 -o output
```

When I run ./output, I receive the following on my terminal

```
Thread 1 is running with thread ID: 140594340370176
Thread 2 is running with thread ID: 140594331977472
GoodBye World
./build.sh: line 2:  7864 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) ./output
```

I am wondering why I am getting Segmentation Fault. I have tried to debug with PyErr_Print(); but that has not given me any clues.

Any feed back is appreciated.

Comment: You're calling `Py_Initialize` and `Py_Finalize`multiple times

Comment: I was under the impression that the Python engine had global state, which isn't thread safe, nor even allows more than one Python "context" to run concurrently.  In contrast to the Lua engine which has the engine state stored in a "context" variable, so there can be multiple Lua scripts running concurrently or interleaved.  (I may be mistaken.  Or things may have changed since I had picked up that bit of information.)

Comment: I removed `Py_Initialize` and `Py_Finalize` from the function, but It is still inconsistent, sometimes it gives me the segmentation fault error, sometimes both scripts run successfully with no segmentation fault, sometimes only one script runs successfully.

Comment: @Eljay I don't believe that things have changed. I remember having read somewhere things might change with Python 4. However, calling the Python interpreter from distinct threads is a bad idea for sure.

Comment: FYI: From [Python doc. - threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html): _In CPython, due to the Global Interpreter Lock, only one thread can execute Python code at once (even though certain performance-oriented libraries might overcome this limitation)._

Comment: Concerning Python 4.0... Sorry, I believe I didn't notice the actual message: [Programming languages: Why Python 4.0 might never arrive, according to its creator](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/programming-languages-why-python-4-0-will-probably-never-arrive-according-to-its-creator/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After testing and debugging the program for about 20 minutes I found that the **problem is** caused because in your example you've created the second `std::thread` named `second` before calling `join()` on the `first` thread.

Thus, to **solve** this just make sure that you've used `first.join()` before creating the `second` thread as shown below:

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    Py_Initialize();
    PyRun_SimpleString("import sys");
    PyRun_SimpleString("sys.path.append(\".\")");
    std::thread first (launchScript,"script.py");
    std::cout << "Thread 1 is running with thread ID: " << first.get_id() << std::endl;
//--vvvvvvvvvvvvv-------->call join on first thread before creating the second std::thread
    first.join();
    
    std::thread second (launchScript,"script2.py");
    std::cout << "Thread 2 is running with thread ID: " << second.get_id() << std::endl;
   
    second.join();
 
    Py_Finalize();
    return 0; 
   
}
```